# How to force Matlab/Simulink Coder to use the parameters created in simulink

Tags: matlab, object, structure, simulink, matlab-coder

I have a simulink model using matlab function blocks.

When i try to generate the C code from my model, the structures parameter scopes i used to represent my data are unused :
When i say unused i mean, 
         matlab coder creates a header file with all my structures defined.
         but in the actual algorithms, when the structure should be sent as argument to a function, matlab coder just defines new variables for each of the fields of which values are hardcoded.

So something like : Function(parameter); with parameter contraining X = 5 and Y = 8 becomes Function(5,8); once generated (so the function definition creating new variables for each of the fields).

You can imagine how messy that gets once the structures get too big.

A friend of mine told me objects dont work with matlab coder. So replacing my structs with objects is not an option unless my friend was wrong.

Does anyone know how i could force matlab coder to actually use the structures i defined for him?
Or maybe there is another solution that i did not think of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my own question.

In the configuration file of the code generation, under "Optimization" tab, change "default parameter behaviour" from 'inlined' to 'tunable'.

I hope this will help others :)